# optimization tasks for schedule

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, bin-packing

I searched on google the answer to my question but I could not find the answer.

here is the problem :

- every week I have several tasks to do
- each task is worth a number of point and takes a certain amount of time to do
- every day of the week I have to do tasks that are worth all the points of the day
- every day I have a finite time to complete these tasks
- I'm trying to determine the ideal distribution of tasks for the week

I'm not sure of being clear so here's an example:

monday: 16 pts in 4,5 hours

Tuesday: 14 pts in 4,5 hours

Wednesday: 10 pts in 2 hours

...

10 x task 1: 0,72 pt in 15 min

10 x task 2: 0,6 pt in 15 min

9 x task 3: 0,89 pt in 15 min

...

find the optimal distribution of tasks

like

monday : 2 x task 1 + 3 x task 2

...

Thank you in advance for your answer. :)

Comment: This seems a bit broad, like you're basically just asking someone to implement an algorithm for you, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I do not necessarily want the algorithm but to know if there is something to solve it. I'm not very good at programming but I like mathematics

Comment: For someone with a math-background that's quite informal. The general approach is mixed-integer programming. If there are more specialized approaches or alternative depends somewhat on the specifics.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. Maybe the Multiple knapsack problem.